# I am getting "'navBar' is defined but never used no-unused-vars" warning .How to solve it? (React App)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import './App.css';
import Search from './components/HomePage/SearchBar';
import navBar from './components/common/Header.js';
import footer from './components/common/Footer.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <navBar />
      <h1>headd</h1> 
      <footer />
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.js
the  element is visible on the page,
But not the navBar and footer.

Here's the Header.js file which exports navBar

```
export function navBar(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul className="navbar"> 
                    <li><h3>FindTheFlat</h3></li>
                    <li><a href="default.asp">LOGIN/SIGN-UP</a></li>
        
                </ul>
        
            </div>

        </div>

    )

}
```

The navBar is getting exported but isn't being used even after calling
Need help on this.

Comment: Babel needs JSX component names to start with a capital case character: `NavBar` --> `<NavBar />` in order to transpile it correctly  as JSX.

Comment: More details on the issue [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason is that you called your component with a lowercase name.

`navBar` and it should be `Navbar.`
the reason for that is that React will be confused between the custom component `JSX` and HTML elements

for  your [referance](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
> built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
> or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
> capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
> correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
> component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
> capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Comment: That reference is not the reason of the issue, this is the right reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 1):

Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.

React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.

See more here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

So, React not use your user-defined component (`<navBar />`, `<footer />`). It uses instead DOM tags